# How do I make this background repeat horizontally the entire way across the screen?

Tags: css, background, background-image

I am using an image as a background.  It is only a few pixels wide so I am having it repeat across the width of the screen.  For some reason, it stops slightly before the right side of the browser window (between a centimeter and an inch depending on your pixel settings).  Here is the css I am using:

```
#bgcontainer { margin:0; padding:0; background:url(images/main_bg.gif) top repeat-x;}
```

How do I get rid of the white column at the end and make the background image repeat all the way to the end?  The site is up at avidest.com so you can see that if you scroll all the way to the right there is a white column.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried background-repeat:repeat-x

```
#bgcontainer { margin:0; padding:0; background:url(images/main_bg.gif); background-repeat:repeat-x
;}
```

Comment: Adam, I posted another question similar to this if you wouldn't mind helping.  Thanks a lot.     [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971930/why-isnt-the-footer-going-all-the-way-from-left-to-right)

Answer (score 0):

set the background css to body tag, maybe this can help you solve your problem

```
body { margin:0; padding:0; background:url(images/main_bg.gif) top repeat-x;}
```